# String.fromCharCode() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, encryption

So, I'm trying to make a simple encryption and decryption application where the user inputs are upped by some amount of characters. For Eg: user inputs "abcd" then it converts to "bcde".

Code used for encryption:

```js
const encryptedInput = (input) => {
  try {
    // convert to array
    let splitInput = sanitize(input).split("");

    //down the characters by derived
    let mapped = splitInput.map((element) =>
      element == " "
        ? element
        : String.fromCharCode(element.charCodeAt(0) + process.env.NUMBEROFCHARS)
    );

    let encryptedInput = mapped.join(""); // result
    return encryptedInput; //return
  } catch (err) {}
};
```

The above code works perfectly fine. Its when I try to decrypt it back to original form, It gives me weird symbols and not the original message.

Code used for decryption:

```js
const decryptedInput = (input) => {
  try {
    // convert to array
    let splitInput = sanitize(input).split("");

    //down the characters by derived
    let mapped = splitInput.map((element) =>
      element == " "
        ? element
        : String.fromCharCode(element.charCodeAt(0) - process.env.NUMBEROFCHARS)
    );

    let decryptedInput = mapped.join(""); // result
    return decryptedInput; //return
  } catch (err) {}
};
```

## **Output / Result**:

**During encryption:**
*Input*: abcd
*Output*: bcde

**During decryption:**
*Input*: bcde
*Output*: ϕϟϩϳ

But I want the output as abcd not ϕϟϩϳ.

Comment: How is it related to node js?

Comment: cuz i'm using it on my backend for tokens and stuff

Comment: _"...not working as intended" is not a useful error/problem description nor a useful summary. The encryption part of your ceaser cipher subtracts a number so _"user inputs "abcd" then it converts to "bcde""_ is impossible. Also what's the value of `NUMBEROFCHARS`? That has to be huge to shift an ASCII character into the unicode range.

Comment: That’s not how tag system work. You only add the tags which describe the problem. Node.JS is no where in your problem so you don’t add it.

Comment: @ArchitGargi `process.env.NUMBEROFCHARS` is node related and can absolutely be the source of the problem. The `node` tag is therefor correct.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag.

Comment: I have .env file where from where the NUMBEROFCHARS comes from.

Comment: Start debugging your script. Step through the decryption part, check the values if they make sense, find the exact place/time/value where the problem occurs, ...

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine. [link for code](https://codepen.io/gp-adhikari/pen/QWQPWJb). Here is the actual code of mine.

Comment: I also changed the process.env.NUMBEROFCHARS to 1 and it gives me same result

Comment: You might be missing a `parseInt()` around `process.env.NUMBEROFCHARS`?

Comment: @Bergi the code is working now and I didn't change anything. I just restarted my pc.

Answer (score 1):

So I restarted my pc and the code works now.